# get special tags with achor in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I've HTML code like below.

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
          </ul>
```

I want to use anchor url on codeigniter but on this HTML there is additional tags for .

<**i class="fa fa-circle-o">** Level One

How to use that "i class" on anchor function ?

I've try this one, but it seems doesn't works.

```
<li><?php echo anchor('link','this link', array('class' => 'fa fa-circle-o')) ?></li>
```

Comment: It is possible to extend function in html helper to accept one more string parameter / false by default prepending text.

Comment: Edit: not html, but url helper.

Comment: hi tpojka, sorry i'm not getting clear, if you can show me some example, it will be more better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load `url` helper before using `anchor` function

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

then

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
```

Can be written as

```
<li><?= anchor('#',"<i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Level One"); ?></li>
```